# Unity Addressables assets not updated

Tags: unity-game-engine, addressables

I'm switching an AR Project that use assetbundles to Addressables but I have some questions.

I have the main project (called A) that receive assets from remote server and the second project (called B) with inside the assets and the assetbundles generation process.

Using addressables I tried this:

- in the project "B" I installed addressables and configured Groups and Profiles. In
  Profiles I set the Remote server adddress. When I run the
  addressables build the first time I put the  generated files to the
  remote server and from the second time I set the Play Mode Script to
  Use Existing Build.
- in the project "A" I installed addressables and configured a empty group and in Profiles I set remote server address. In my code I load catalog remote and I obtain the asset correctly.

The problem is when I modify the asset. From the project "B" I rebuild with Use Existing Build enabled, put the generated files to the remote server and run the project "A", but the asset is that old.

I can't understand where I'm wrong, someone can help me please?
Thanks

Comment: Someone can help me please? Some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and it was so difficult to find a solution.

My problem was mainly because of the asset cache downloaded.
Even if we uncheck the use Bundle cache, the problem still exists as the catalog cache is downloaded.

**Solution**

use a script to delete the cache folder on every game load. Then load the object.

I hope this helps